# implementation of TextArea in libgdx Scene2D

Tags: android, libgdx

is there a way to implement TextArea in libgdx scene2D ui? i look on their ui list there is no TextArea, their TextField could only display 1 line not multi. thanks

Answer (score 1):

A litle bit old but libgdx finally implemented TextArea with latest version

Answer (score 0):

Do read the API from a TextField.  It's an InputField.

> A single-line text input field.

Depending on the case you can use a BitmapFont to draw text in your loop or do use a Label. It can handle multiple lines as you whish. With the `.setWrappedText("test\ntest")`you can even have a simple linebreak.